# Binding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ember.js

this is my first post in stackoverflow.

I'm new to ember.js and i've been studying ember.js.

I'm building a small app to learn ember.js now,but binding doesn't work somehow.

Please give me a help!!

```
#------------------------Controller------------------------


App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();

App.monstersController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({

content:[],

//some code to add model instances to content...

counter: function(){
var content = this.get('content');
return content.get('length');
}.property('length')

});


#------------------------View------------------------


App.StatsView = Ember.View.extend({
counterBinding : 'App.monstersController.counter',



#------------------------HTML------------------------

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">

//some code here

{{#view App.StatsView}}Counter: {{counter}}{{/view}}

//I'm expecting the length of content array in App.monstersController above.

//some code here

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a value off of a view you need to access it via `{{view.counter}}`.

However, in your case you should probably be setting the controller on the view like:

```
App.StatsView = Ember.View.extend({
  controllerBinding : 'App.monstersController'
})
```

Once you get the hang of that, I'd look into setting up a router to manage binding controllers and views together.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

I changed {{counter}} to {{view.counter}} and it worked!!
Im confused why I need to add "view",though...

I'll keep studying ember.

Again,Thanks so much!!

Comment: A template has a context from which the values are extracted. By default it is set to the controller attached to the view. In earlier versions of Ember the context was actually the view itself, but with the introduction of the router and controllers it made more sense to set the context to the object a view was representing rather than the view itself